# Definite improper integral of gaussian divided by shifted exponential

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have to solve the following integral:

$$I_{a}(b)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ax^2+bx}}{1+e^x}dx$$ If $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ then i know the solution, since one can use partial fractions, i.e.
$$
I_{a}(b)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}\frac{e^{bx}}{1+e^x}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}\frac{((1+e^{x})-1)^b}{1+e^x}dx=...
$$
The equation reduces to a sum of integrals of the form $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2+bx}dx$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ax^2}}{1+e^x}dx$. These lasts integrals mathematica was able to calculate. So by now i have the solution for $I_{a}(b)\space \forall b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

$$
I_{a}(b>0)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\left(\frac{(-1)^b}{2}+\sum_{i=1}^{b}(-1)^{b-i}e^{\frac{(i-1)^2}{4a}}\right)\\
$$
$$
I_{a}(b=0)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\frac{(-1)^b}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\frac{1}{2}
$$
$$
I_{a}(b<0)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\left(\frac{(-1)^b}{2}+\sum_{i=b}^{-1}(-1)^{b-i}e^{\frac{i^2}{4a}}\right)
$$

I've noticed further that for all $b$ that are non-integers, i can use the same method and the integral reduces to a sum of integrals like above with one exception: i have one term like
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}\frac{e^{bx}}{1+e^x}dx$$
with $0<b<1$. With this condition it holds $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{bx}}{1+e^x}=\pi \csc(\pi b)$ according to mathematica - i.e. a finite area beneath this term.

And now i'm stuck. I've found out $\int\frac{e^{bx}}{1+e^x}dx=_2F_1(1,b;1+b;-e^x)$ i.e. an ordinary hypergeometric function (notation according [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)). The gaussian also has an antiderivative (including the Error function). But the product seems not. I've tried substitution, "differentiation under the integral sign" and integration by parts, but i go in circles.

In the following  picture i've plotted $I_{a=1}(b)$ (note: logarithmic-scaled y-axis). The blue points are points at $b\in\mathbb{Z}$, which i'm able to calculate exactly. I've inserted numerically evaluated points (NIntegrate in mathematica) in green at $b+\frac{1}{2},\space b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

[image]

It's so frustrating, because the non-integer points seem to interpolate the known data points - yet i'm unable to come up with the formula.

Could anyone please help me to evaluate
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}\frac{e^{bx}}{1+e^x}dx$$
with $0<b<1$ or show some other way how to get the analytical solution for a non-integer $b$?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I've also thought about an _analytic continuation_ of the given formulas from the integers to the real numbers, but the alternatig terms make it non-trivial!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using
$$\frac 1{1+e^x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{E_n(0)}{2 n!} x^n$$
$$I_n=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-a x^2+bx}  x^n\,dx$$
$$J_n=2  a^{\frac{n+2}{2}}\,I_n$$
$$J_n=b \left(1-(-1)^n\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{n+2}{2};\frac{3}{2};\frac{b^2}{4 a}\right)+$$ $$\sqrt{a}
   \left(1+(-1)^n\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{n+1}{2};\frac{1}{2};\frac{b^2}{4 a}\right)$$ leading to

$$I_{2m}=a^{-(m+\frac{1}{2})}\, \Gamma \left(\frac{2m+1}{2} \right) \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{2m+1}{2} ;\frac{1}{2};\frac{b^2}{4 a}\right)$$
$$I_{2m+1}=b\,a^{-(m+\frac{3}{2})}\, \Gamma \left(\frac{2m+3}{2}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{2m+3}{2};\frac{3}{2};\frac{b^2}{4 a}\right)$$

Comment: Sorry for the great delay and thank you very much for answering!! Sadly I don't know, what $E_n(0)$ is supposed to be

Comment: @JoHe. Euler polynomials

Comment: Thank you so much!